# Substitute command output into another bash command but preserving newlines at the same time?

Tags: bash, command, arguments, newline, substitution

I would like to call a bash command in the following form:

```
command1 argv1 "$(command2 arg)"
```

The subtituted command would be the second argument of command1.
Problem is that output of command2 contains `"\n"` sequences, not really newlines but `"\\n"` sequences, which are outputted as newlines. Preserving newlines in command one should use syntax `$'\n'`. However I can't use both:

```
$'$(command2 arg)'
```

or

```
$($'command2 arg')
```

Neither of them work. What should I do to make command subtitution working in this scenario?

Comment: there is also an `$"stuff\n"` form you could try. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Isn't `$"..."` for translation into locales? See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Locale-Translation

Comment: @BenjaminW : Yes, I know that is the main purpose for `$"..."`. But it would seem that the `"..."` would allow for variable substitutions, where as `'....'` doesn't. O.P. question doesn't have testable code, so I'll leave it to him to check. Good luck to all.

Comment: Provide a minimal verifiable input with an expected output.

Comment: Try `var=$(command2 arg); command1 argv1 "$var"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the first line of `command2`'s output, use:

```
command1 argv1 $(command2 arg | head -n1)
```

If you want to use every line of `command2`'s output as arguments for `command1`, just don't quote the command substitution:

```
command1 argv1 $(command2 arg)
```

Bash will use the output without its newlines, using spaces instead. For example:

```
$ seq 3
1
2
3
$ echo "$(seq 3)"
1
2
3
$ echo $(seq 3)
1 2 3
```